# select record from mysql that were inserted in last (3,4,5) days from current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

select record from mysql that were inserted (3,4,5) days  from current date

example: select id from tbl where date(created)IN (3,4,5)

```
select JOB_TBL_ID from job_post where DAYOFMONTH(date(CREATED)) IN (3,4,15)
```

tbl:job_post

```
''''''''''''|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''|
JOB_TBL_ID  |  CREATED                  |
'''''''''''''|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
1            |2015-07-01 18:06:32
2             2015-06-30 19:14:42
```

Comment: i want to fetch record which are inserted in last (3,4,5) days  from current date

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly. What is `(3,4,15) days from current date`?

Comment: first of all try some stuff and then come to SO . show what you have tried??

Comment: @ekad i have tried sql,select JOB_TBL_ID from job_post where DAYOFMONTH(date(CREATED)) IN (3,4,15) but not working

Comment: do you tried DATE BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ??

Comment: i have only date on which record were inserted

Comment: What you really want ?? (3,4,5)days OR (3,4,15)days ???

Comment: @Geo ,I am using searching with checkbox with no.of days on click on it, i am getting an array of days , so with the use of days in array, i have to fetch record

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF function like this

```
select id from tbl where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date(created)) IN (3,4,15,7,8)
```

Comment: ,i have tried select JOB_TBL_ID from job_post where DATEDIFF(date(CREATED),NOW()) IN (3,4,45) ,but not working

Comment: Specify you data of table.

Comment: i am unable to post screenshot,my reputation is 1, datatable is simple there are date to each record ex: CREATED in datetime format and other column such as id ,one of the date example is 2015-06-27 14:51:47

Comment: I have tried this ,but returns empty , select * from job_post where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date(CREATED)) IN (3,4,15)

Comment: @Manoj what's problem if it is help out then given vote and right mark

Comment: This answer is not solving my problem

Comment: @manoj You are not given data how can i help you but your data ahead 2015-06-27 14:51:47 date to check 11 days like IN (3,4,15,11)

Comment: I have a record of date 2015-07-01 18:06:32,  but query is showing empty

Comment: @Manoj this date also difference of current date 7 days how to get result

Comment: I have posted table structure,have a look

Comment: @Manoj now check it your post two date

Comment: but my date is between the no. if days provided

Answer (score 0):

The code is not a perfect one. Choose this only if no other solutions satisfies you.

```
$condition='';
foreach($YOUR_SELECTED_DATES as $value)
{
  if($condition!='')
      $condition.=" OR ";
  $condition.=" date(CREATED) = ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL ".$value." DAY ) ";
}

$your_qry="select JOB_TBL_ID from job_post where ".$condition;
```

Comment: no.of day can vary according to the user ,so query should not be hard coded

Comment: ,i am getting only days in integer form like 2,3,4 which will be the  input to query